# Using large numbers of permutations in parallel: combining iterpc and foreach

Tags: r, parallel-processing, iterator, permutation

Iterpc begins each loop from the same point. This has created an amusing, though frustrating issue, illustrated below:

```
####Load Packages:
library("doParallel")
library("foreach")
library("iterpc")

####Define variables:    
n<-2
precision<-0.1 
support<-matrix(seq(0+precision,1-precision,by=precision), ncol=1) 
nodes<-2 #preparing for multicore.
cl<-makeCluster(nodes)

####Prep iterations
I<-iterpc(table(support),n, ordered=TRUE,replace=FALSE)
steps<-((factorial(length(support)) / factorial(length(support)-n)))/n

####Run loop to get the combined values:
registerDoParallel(cl) 
  support_n<-foreach(m=1:n,.packages="iterpc", .combine='cbind') %dopar% {
    t(getnext(I,steps))
  } #????
```

Which returns

```
support_n
```

I was hoping that this would run each of the sets in parallel, one half of the permutations assigned to each node.   However, it only does the first half of the permutations... twice. ([,1] is equal to [,37].)  How do I get it to return all of permutations and combine them in parallel?

Assume there will be an arbitrarily large number of permutations so memory management and speed are nontrivial.

Previous research:[All possible permutations for large n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33596777/all-possible-permutations-for-large-n/33597477?noredirect=1#comment56164683_33597477)

Comment: what packages do I need to load make this run? `iterpc`, `foreach`,  `parallel`, ... apparently `doParallel` as well?  Can you edit your code to make it fully reproducible?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the question; but, I think you need to explicitly tell the cores which chunks you wish to do--which in this case means setting up your iterator `I` differently. Otherwise, I think you could use a lock. But I don't think that will provide the speed up you wish.

Comment: IE - split the permutations required to separate `I`s and then run each set of permutations in parallel.

Comment: I was hoping that this would run each of the sets in parallel, one half of the permutations assigned to each node.  How could I split the permutations?

Comment: To do what you describe as your goal would require a lock. But that wouldn't give you a speed up because you'd just have 1 processor waiting while the other was working... as to how to split this example, I think you need to work that out on paper... IE- `0.1 - 0.5`, `0.6 - 0.9`, then split the remaining (crossover) permutations you've missed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation I believe the following does in fact execute the command in parallel.

`registerDoParallel(cl)
 system.time(
     support_n<-foreach(a=getnext(I,d=(2*steps)),.combine='cbind') %dopar% a
 )
 support_n<-t(support_n)`

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Just for anyone, who will come here by searching "foreach iterpc R", as i did. 
Your approach marked as accepted answer does not really differ much from

```
result <- foreach(a=1:10)  %dopar% {
  a
}
```

because `a=getnext(I,d=(2*steps))` will simply return the first `2*steps` combinations and then `foreach` package will iterate in parallel over this combinations.

When you have very large number of combinations returned by `iterpc` (which it is build for) you cannot in fact use such an approach.

In that case the only thing i believe one could do is to write iterator wrapper over the `iterpc` object.

```
# register parallel backend
library(doParallel) 
registerDoParallel(cores = 3)

#create iterpc object
library(iterpc)
combinations <- iterpc(4,2)

library(iterators) 

iterpc_iterator <- function(iterpc_object, iteration_length) {
  # one's own function of nextElement() because iterpc 
  # returns NULL on finished iteration on subsequent getnext() invocation
  # but not 'StopIteration'
  nextEl <- function() {
    if (iteration_length > 0)
      iteration_length <<- iteration_length - 1
    else
      stop('StopIteration')

    getnext(iterpc_object)
  }
  obj <- list(nextElem=nextEl)
  class(obj) <- c('irep', 'abstractiter', 'iter')
  obj
}

it <- iterpc_iterator(combinations, getlength(combinations)) 

library(foreach)
result <- foreach(i=it) %dopar% {
  i
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [iterpc::iter_wrapper](http://search.r-project.org/library/iterpc/html/iter_wrapper.html).
The relevant line from your example:

```
support_n <-foreach(a = iter_wrapper(I), .combine='cbind') %dopar% a
```